# HTML5 Canvas: Get Event when drawing is finished

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, dom-events, drawimage

I'm drawing an image to a canvas element. I then have code that depends on this process to be finished. My code looks like this:

```
var myContext = myCanvasElement.getContext('2d'),
    myImg = new Image();

myImg.onload = function() {
    myContext.drawImage(containerImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);
};

myImg.src = "someImage.png";
```

So now, I would like to be notified when drawImage is done. I checked the spec but I couldn't find either an event or the possibility to pass a callback function. So far I just set a timeout, but this obviously is not very sustainable. How do you solve this problem?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Like almost all Javascript functions, `drawImage` is *synchronous*, i.e. it'll only return once it has actually done what it's supposed to do.

That said, what it's *supposed to do*, like most other DOM calls, is queue-up lists of things to be repainted next time the browser gets into the event loop.

There's no event you can specifically register to tell you when that is, since by the time any such event handler could be called, the repaint would have already happened.

Comment: @Loktar tricky to explain more fully without diluting the answer, I think... :(

Comment: no you're right I reread it and perfectly understood it, I just imagined a new dev saying "synchronous" huh? That's why I ended up deleting my comment.

Comment: @Loktar hopefully my edit adds just enough to make it obvious :)

Comment: Do you have a link to some documentation that says the function is synchronous? Unfortunately (for me), my tests just showed me it's not and I'm a bit confused

Comment: @BBog _all_ JS functions are synchronous, unless documented otherwise.  If you think `.drawImage` is async I'd like to see a jsfiddle that demonstrates it.

Comment: @Alnitak I made a fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/FxrSa/ The alert is shown before the image. However, the alert is shown before the whole jsfiddle site is rendered so it just might be the alert test causing my problem

Comment: @BBog curious - I see what you mean.  The W3C spec for `canvas` doesn't say anything about this behaviour.  I'm still looking into it...

Comment: @BBog right, that'll be because the `drawImage` repaint doesn't happen until the event loop regains control, but `alert()` blocks the browser before that point.   In _general use_ `drawImage` should behave synchronously.

Comment: @MatthewCornelisse can you throw up a demo that shows this?

Answer (score 7):

Jef Claes explains it pretty well [on his website](http://www.jefclaes.be/2010/12/html5-drawing-images-to-canvas-gotcha.html):

> Browsers load images asynchronously while scripts are already being
>   interpreted and executed.  If the image isn't fully loaded the canvas
>   fails to render it.
>
> Luckily this isn't hard to resolve. We just have to wait to start
>   drawing until we receive a callback from the image, notifying loading
>   has completed.

```
<script type="text/javascript">        
window.addEventListener("load", draw, true);

function draw(){                                    
    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_0sKGHtXHSes/TPt5KD-xQDI/AAAAAAAAA0s/udx3iWAzUeo/s1600/aspnethomepageplusdevtools.PNG";                
    img.onload = function(){
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        var context = canvas.getContext('2d');    

        context.drawImage(img, 0, 0);        
    };            
}
```

Comment: this is completely irrelevant to the question asked - the OP was already using an `onload` handler.

Answer (score 2):

You already have an event when the image loads, and you do one thing (draw). Why not do another and call the function that will do whatever it is you want done after `drawImage`? Literally just:

```
myImg.onload = function() {
    myContext.drawImage(containerImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);
    notify(); // guaranteed to be called after drawImage
};
```

Comment: It doesn't seem to be called after drawImage... the test I just made showed me the drawImage method is not done synchronously

Answer (score 0):

`drawImage()` as any drawing method on the 2D canvas in itself is "mostly" synchronous.
You can assume that any code that needs a read-back of the pixels will have the updated pixels. Also, for `drawImage` in particular, you can even assume that the image will have been fully decoded "synchronously", which can take some time with big images.

*Technically, in most modern configs the actual painting work will be deferred to the GPU, which implies some parallelization and some asynchronicity, but read-backs will wait for the GPU has done its work and lock the CPU for that time.*

However the drawing on the canvas is only the first step of the full rendering of the canvas to the monitor.
The canvas then needs to go through the CSS compositor, where it will get painted along the rest of the page. This is what is deferred to the next rendering step.
`alert()` in Chrome does currently block the CSS compositor, and thus, even though the actual pixels of the canvas buffer have been updated, these changes haven't been reflected by the CSS compositor yet. (*In Firefox `alert()` triggers a kind of "spin the event loop" which allows the CSS compositor to still kick in, even if the global tasks of the event loop are paused*).

To hook to the CSS compositor, there is a [`requestPostAnimationFrame` method](https://github.com/WICG/request-post-animation-frame) that is being incubated, but apparently got dropped of Chrome experiments recently.

We can polyfill it using both `requestAnimationFrame` and a MessageEvent to hook to the next task as soon as possible (`setTimeout` is generally given less priority).

Now, even this `requestPostAnimationFrame` is only an event for when the browser's compositor kicked in, there is still some time before that image gets to the OS compositor and to the monitor (about a full V-Sync frame).

Some configuration of Chrome on Windows have access to a shortcut that allows the browser to talk directly to the OS compositor, and bypasses the CSS compositor. To enable this option, you can create your 2D context with the [`desynchhronized`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/canvas.html#dom-canvasrenderingcontext2dsettings-desynchronized) option set to true. However, this option is only supported in a few configurations.

Below is a demo of almost all this:

```js
// requestPostAnimationFrame polyfill
if (typeof requestPostAnimationFrame !== "function") {
  (() => {
    const channel = new MessageChannel();
    const callbacks = [];
    let timestamp = 0;
    let called = false;
    let scheduled = false; // to make it work from rAF
    let inRAF = false; // to make it work from rAF
    channel.port2.onmessage = e => {
      called = false;
      const toCall = callbacks.slice();
      callbacks.length = 0;
      toCall.forEach(fn => {
        try {
          fn(timestamp);
        } catch (e) {}
      });
    }
    // We need to overwrite rAF to let us know we are inside an rAF callback
    // as to avoid scheduling yet an other rAF, which would be one painting frame late
    // We could have hooked an infinite loop on rAF, but this means
    // forcing the document to be animated all the time
    // which is bad for perfs
    const rAF = globalThis.requestAnimationFrame;
    globalThis.requestAnimationFrame = function(...args) {
      if (!scheduled) {
        scheduled = true;
        rAF.call(globalThis, (time) => inRAF = time);
        globalThis.requestPostAnimationFrame(() => {
          scheduled = false;
          inRAF = false;
        });
      }
      rAF.apply(globalThis, args);
    };
    globalThis.requestPostAnimationFrame = function(callback) {
      if (typeof callback !== "function") {
        throw new TypeError("Argument 1 is not callable");
      }
      callbacks.push(callback);
      if (!called) {
        if (inRAF) {
          timestamp = inRAF;
          channel.port1.postMessage("");
        } else {
          requestAnimationFrame((time) => {
            timestamp = time;
            channel.port1.postMessage("");
          });
        }
        called = true;
      }
    };
  })();
}

// now the demo

// if the current browser can use desync 2D context
// let's try it there too
// (I couldn't test it myself, so let me know in comments)
const supportsDesyncContext = CanvasRenderingContext2D.prototype.getContextAttributes && 
  document.createElement("canvas")
    .getContext("2d", { desynchronized: true })
    .getContextAttributes().desynchronized;

test(false);
if (supportsDesyncContext) {
  setTimeout(() => test(true), 1000);
}

async function test(desync) {
  const canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
  document.body.append(canvas);
  const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d", { desynchronized: desync });
  const blob = await fetch("https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/47/PNG_transparency_demonstration_1.png")
    .then((resp) => resp.ok && resp.blob());
  const bitmap = await createImageBitmap(blob);
  ctx.drawImage(bitmap, 0, 0, 300, 150);
  // schedule our callback after rendering
  requestPostAnimationFrame(() => {
    alert("Right after CSS compositing");
  });
  // prove that we actually already painted on the canvas
  // even if the CSS compositor hasn't kicked in yet
  const pixelOnCanvas = ctx.getImageData(120,120,1,1).data;
  alert("Before CSS compositing." + (desync ? " (desynchronized)": "") + "\nPixel on canvas: " + pixelOnCanvas);
}
```

Comment: Does a `postMessage()` event handler run at a different time than a `promise.resolve().then()` callback? Are you saying here that Promise microtasks happen before paint and postMessage (micro?)tasks happen after paint; that they are not on the same schedule?

Comment: Oh wow, I didn't know [queueMicrotask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/queueMicrotask) was a thing these days. Where have I been!

Comment: @trusktr `postMessage()` will queue a *task*. `Promise.resolve().then()` will queue a microtask. They are completely different. The `postMessage` task will get executed at the next event loop's iteration as part of its first step. The microtask will get executed as soon as the JS stack is empty, that is the microtask queue is emptied many times per event-loop's iteration. Also, a microtask queued from an other microtask will get executed from the same microtask-checkpoint, no way to get out of it. So you can't schedule anything using microtasks, `f = ()=>Promise.then(f);f()` is `while(1)`

Comment: Ah. Thanks. The conversation at https://github.com/whatwg/html/issues/4905 clears that up by pointing to the relevant parts of spec (postMessage queues a macrotask that browsers tend to prioritize and run sooner than setTimeout(0)).

Answer (score -1):

The answer by @MikeGledhill (that got deleted) is essentially the beginning of the answer, though it could have explained it better, and browsers may not have all had the `requestAnimationFrame` API available at that time:

Painting of pixels happens in the next animation frame. This means that if you call `drawImage`, the screen pixels won't actually be updated at that time, but in the next animation frame.

There's no event for this.

But! We can use `requestAnimationFrame` to schedule a callback for the next frame before paint (display update) happens:

```js
myImg.onload = function() {
    myContext.drawImage(containerImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // This function will run in the next animation frame, *right before*
      // the browser will update the pixels on the display (paint).

        // To ensure that we run logic *after* the display has been
        // updated, an option is to queue yet one more callback
        // using setTimeout.
        setTimeout(() => {
            // At this point, the page rendering has been updated with the
            // `drawImage` result (or a later frame's result, see below).
        }, 0)
    })
};
```

What is happening here:

The `requestAnimtionFrame` call schedules a function that will be called right before the browser updated display pixels. After this callback is completed, the browser will continue to synchronously update the display pixels in a following tick that is very similar to a microtask.

The "microtask"-like in which the browser updates the display, happens after your `requestAnimationFrame` callback, and happens *after* all user-created microtasks that a user creates in the callback using `Promise.resolve().then()` or an `await` statement. This means one cannot make deferred code fire immediately (synchronously) after the paint task happens.

The only way to guarantee that logic will fire after the next paint task, is to use `setTimeout` ([or a `postMessage` trick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18826570/settimeout0-vs-window-postmessage-vs-messageport-postmessage)) to queue a *macrotask* (not microtask) from an animation frame callback. A macrotask queued from a `requestAnimationFrame` callback will fire *after* all microtasks and microtask-likes, including the task that updates the pixels. The setTimeout (or postMessage) macrotask will not fire synchronously after animation frame microtasks.

This approach is not perfect though. *Most of the time*, the macrotask queued from `setTimeout` (and more likely with `postMessage`) will fire *before the next animation frame and paint cycle*. But, due to the specification of `setTimeout` (and `postMessage`), there is no guarantee that the delay will be exactly what we specify (`0` in this example), and the browser is free to use heuristics and/or hard-coded values like 2ms to determine when is the soonest time to run a `setTimeout` (macrotask) callback.

Due to this non-guaranteed non-synchronous nature of macrotask scheduling, it is *possible*, though in practice unlikely, that your `setTimeout` (or `postMessage`) callback can fire not just after the current animation frame (and the paint cycle that updates the display), but after the *next* animation frame (and its paint task), meaning that a macrotask callback has a small chance firing too late for the frame you were targeting. This chance is reduced when using `postMessage` instead of `setTimeout`.

That being said, this sort of thing is probably something you should not do unless you're trying to write tests that capture painted pixels and compare them to expected results or something similar.

In general, you should schedule any drawing logic (f.e. `ctx.drawImage()`) using `requestAnimationFrame`, never rely on the actual timing of the paint update, and assume that the user will see what the browser APIs guarantee you've specified for them to see (the browsers have their own tests in place for ensuring their APIs work).

Finally, we don't know what your actual goal is. Most likely this answer may be irrelevant to that goal.

---

Here's the same example using the `postMessage` trick:

```js
let messageKey = 0

myImg.onload = function() {
    myContext.drawImage(containerImg, 0, 0, 300, 300);

    requestAnimationFrame(() => {
      // This function will run in the next animation frame, *right before*
      // the browser will update the pixels on the display (paint).

        const key = "Unique message key for after paint callback: "+ messageKey++

        // To ensure that we run logic *after* the display has been
        // updated, an option is to queue yet one more callback
        // using postMessage.

        const afterPaint = (event) => {
            // Ignore interference from any other messaging in the app.
            if (event.data != key) return

            removeEventListener('message', afterPaint)

            // At this point, the page rendering has been updated with the
            // `drawImage` result (or a later frame's result, but
            // more unlikely than with setTimeout, as per above).
        }

        addEventListener('message', afterPaint)

         // Hack: send a message which arrives back to us in a
         // following macrotask, more likely sooner than with
         // setTimeout.
        postMessage(key, '*')
    })
};
```

Comment: Comparing this to a microtask is very confusing. It doesn't match anything of a microtask, it just happens after, but you can very well schedule a **task** to fire in between an rAF callback and the next rendering, for instance ResiveObserver callbacks will fire in this intertime. Also, that rendering task is actually itself one "frame" before the monitor's rendering happens, in this rendering phase the browser will ask the OS compositor to update the monitor's pixel, which will happen only one frame later.

Comment: However some configurations have access to a `desynchronized` option for their 2D context, which will allow their browser to use a shortcut only for that canvas, but this is only available in a few configs (win + chrome).

Comment: @Kaiido Yeah, maybe "microtask" is not exactly the best term. In a sense the resize observer and paint tasks are *like* microtasks that happen to always run after all user-defined microtasks including any user-defined microtasks chained from user-defined microtasks, as if the resize and paint tasks are always pushed to the end of the queue, or as if user microtasks are always inserted before them. They are definitely not like macrotasks from the perspective of an animation frame task.

Comment: @Kaiido I've updated the answer to call it microtask-like, and explain that the paint microtask-like always happens after "user-created microtasks". I know they are just "tasks" in spec language, but that doesn't differentiate them from setTimeout tasks for example (apart from more complicated wording found in the spec that is difficult to understand).