# I want to be alerted once the canvas is rendered

Tags: javascript, jquery

I draw an image on a canvas with a text, but the canvas takes a long time to render.
I want to be alerted once the canvas is rendered.
This is my script :

```js
function dz_res_click() {
  var canvas = document.getElementById("dz_residence_canvas");
  var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
  var residence = new Image();
  residence.src = "../../imgs/residence.jpg"
  var r_wlaya = document.getElementById("r_wlaya").value;
  residence.onload = function() {
    context.drawImage(residence, 0, 0, 2135, 2843);
    context.font = "bold 70px sans-serif";
    context.textAlign = "right";
    context.fillText(r_wlaya, 1596, 252);
  }
}
```

Comment: So, what is the hard part?

Comment: maybe this link might help  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31299509/call-a-function-when-html5-canvas-is-ready

Comment: the hard part : get alert after canvas drowing finished

Comment: @YashSoni thanks for replay, and i don't get the answer there

Comment: Duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41346772/how-do-i-know-when-html5-canvas-rendering-is-finished

Comment: @Weft there only talk no solution

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution. You just add the alert.

```
residence.onload = function(){
    context.drawImage(residence, 0, 0, 2135, 2843);
    context.font = "bold 70px sans-serif";
    context.textAlign = "right";
    context.fillText(r_wlaya, 1596, 252);
    alert("javascript is synchronous, so unless there is a callback or promise, 
    functions execute in the order in which they are invoked.");
}
```

Comment: thanks for the reply , but the alert is showing before drowing image

Comment: Even though the drawing is not yet visible, the rendering has completed. You could try wrapping the alert in a `setTimeout` if you don't want it to trigger until the drawing is visible. You could also just use a custom alert that doesn't block the thread. I like this one: https://sweetalert.js.org/guides/