# Capture drawing finish event inside an Iframe

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I have an HTML page which contains Iframe with canvas, i want to capture the event of canvas finish drawing.

```
<html>
   <head></head>
   <body>
       <iframe id="myIframe" src="link"/>
   </body>
</html>
```

i tried to use 
myIframe.onload = () => {}

But it runs before canvas rendring. thanks for Help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [HTML5 Canvas: Get Event when drawing is finished](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207606/html5-canvas-get-event-when-drawing-is-finished)

Comment: You can use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage to send a message back to the parent once the process in the iframe stops drawing

Comment: [This thread might help you access the canvas inside your iframe,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088544/get-element-from-within-an-iframe) [and this thread will help you know when your canvas element has finished rendering.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11207606/html5-canvas-get-event-when-drawing-is-finished)

Comment: the iframe and the canvas don't belong to me, so can't change their code, i can get iframe load but not canvas drawing finish.