# How do I know when canvas finish drawing?

Tags: javascript

I have a large image draw by canvas and I want to know when canvas finishes drawing.

Comment: Check: https://stackoverflow.com/q/11207606/9256189

Answer (score 0, accepted):

canvas drawing in synchronous so when you draw like this

```
 canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
```

the next line get excuted when the drawing is finished
so you can do what you wanted to do after drawing like this

```
canvas.getContext('2d').fillRect(25, 25, 100, 100);
//draw finished do something
```